# Condition variable notification and wait

Tags: c++, concurrency

I was going through the code [https://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~sbansal/os/lec/l25.html](https://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/%7Esbansal/os/lec/l25.html)
and I am not able to understand the wait and notify sequence in Consumer and producer . Is the sequence correct of not_full and not_empty condition variable ? In producer it should wait on not_full and notify not_empty and in cosumer it should wait on not_empty and notify on notfull . Is my understanding correct ?

```
int head = 0, tail = 0; 
struct cv not_full, not_empty;
struct lock qlock;

void produce(char data) {
  acquire(&qlock);
   (while ((head + 1) % MAX  ==  tail)) {
    wait(&not_full, &qlock); 
  }
  queue[head] = data;
  head = (head + 1) % MAX;
  notify(&not_full); // Here it will notify the consumer to wake up and processes the data 
  release(&qlock);
}

char consume(void) {
  acquire(&qlock);
  while () {
    wait(&not_empty, &qlock); // consumer will wake up on event from Producer 
  }
  e = queue[tail];
  tail = (tail + 1) % MAX;
  notify(&not_empty);
  release(&qlock);
  return e;
}
```

Comment: `(while ((head + 1) % MAX  ==  tail))` and `while ()` that does not look like C++

Answer (score 1):

> Is the sequence correct of not_full and not_empty condition variable ?

No, looks like there is a typo or mistake in original code, `produce()` should notify `not_empty` as it puts data into queue and `consume()` should notify `not_full` as it takes it. Even logically - it does not make any sense that function notifies variable that it waits on itself.